# This python program is supposed to check matching string but after three wrong input , programming is not terminating

Tags: python

// matching string program

```
exact_word = "Guessing"
    guess_kid = ""
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 3
    out_of_guesses = False

    while guess_kid != exact_word.casefold() and not(out_of_guesses):
        if guess_count < guess_limit:
            guess_kid = input("Enter another word : ")
            guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
    if out_of_guesses:
        print("Out of luck")
    else:
        print("you win")
```

// Program is not terminating after three wrong input

Comment: The indentation is off. The first `else` clause should match the inner `if` clause

Comment: `out_of_guesses` is set after the `while` loop because the `else` block is refering to the `while` instead of the `if` in the `while` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exact_word = "Guessing"
guess_kid = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess_kid != exact_word.casefold() and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess_kid = input("Enter another word : ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
        print("Out of luck")
else:
        print("you win")
```

This will work for you. 
You need to check condition once there is some changes are made in `out_of_guesses`.

Answer (score 1):

The indents are a touch off. Try this:

```
exact_word = "Guessing"
guess_kid = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess_kid != exact_word.casefold() and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess_kid = input("Enter another word : ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

        if out_of_guesses:
            print("Out of luck")
        else:
            print("you win")
```

It's important to keep track of the indent after using loop/clauses. Since we didn't indent before the `while:` loop, I moved the first 5 lines to fully left-aligned.

Because the `while:` loop starts a loop, the next `if` and respective `else` clauses are indented one in. The subset text under those are indented over again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your programme will be terminated after one input. `else:
        print("you win")` see this.